# How to access nested JSON object in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a JSON response that I am converting to a DataFrame in Python.

JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "fields": [
      {
        "title": "ABC",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "title": "DEF",
        "value": "456"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I parse this JSON to a DataFrame, the columns appear as id, `first_name`, `last_name` and `fields`. Where the `fields` column contains the two nested JSON objects:

`[{"title": "ABC","value": "123"},{"title": "DEF","value": "456"}]`

How would I go about splitting the two objects in `fields` as their own columns?

For context, I am trying to print the results of the DataFrame to a csv file, where each object in `fields` has its own column.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC I am using `json_normalize`

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(j, 'fields', ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
Out[1281]: 
  title value last_name first_name      id
0   ABC   123       Doe       John  123456
1   DEF   456       Doe       John  123456
```

---

Data input

```
j=[
  {
    "id": 123456,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "fields": [
      {
        "title": "ABC",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "title": "DEF",
        "value": "456"
      }
    ]

  }

]
```

Comment: Thanks - is there any way that this can be outputted on a single row? Say, using the `title` key as the column header?

Comment: @Matt I am not sure what you need

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve: 

    ABC   DEF last_name first_name      id
0   123   456       Doe       John  123456

Comment: Not too sure how to format the comment. But essentially I am trying to get the `title` key as columns, for example, 5 columns being `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `ABC`, `DEF`.